# Setting an ID type property value from workflow in FileNet

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine, filenet-process-engine

Is it possible to set value for an ID type property from a workflow?

We have a workflow to create a date wise record folder everyday when first mail for that day is ingested in the system *(IBM IER)*. For this we are using `createRMFolder` method from `RM_Operations` component which is OOTB component for IER.

We can set the properties for the new folder by passing them as a string array to the operation. But the issue is we need to set value for an ID type property for the newly created record date folder.

Please suggest if there is way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bundled CE_Operations component. Specifically, you need to use the `setObjectProperty` method passing it the Id object.

Comment: setOjectProperty method value as an attachment. How could I attach the ID object as an attachment to workflow?

Comment: All FN object values are treated as VWAttachment types in CE_Operations. You can get the Id value from an FN object with CE_Operations.getObjectProperty() receiving the Id as VWAttachment which you will then need to pass to setObjectproperty()